# How do you calculate the concentrations of multiple reactants in a certain point in time?

Tags: kinetics

For $\ce{A + B -> C + D}$, given that $v = k [\ce{A}] [\ce{B}]$. I know the derivation for $\ce{A->B + C}$ , being $\ln[\ce{A}]=\ln[\ce{A}]_0−νkt$, but I'd like to know how you can, given a point in time, calculate the concentrations of A and B in the first equation, given the initial concentrations.

Comment: You need to perform integration for that. Relate both $\ce{[A]}$ and $\ce{[B]}$ with a single variable.

Comment: Assuming $[\ce{A}]_0 =  [\ce{B}]_0$, it all boils down to a second order kinetics with $v = k[\ce{A}]^2$.

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{dA}{dt}=-kAB$$
$$\frac{dB}{dt}=-kAB$$subject to initial conditions $A=A_0$ and $B=B_0$ at time t = 0.  Let x = number of moles of A that react = number of moles of B that react.  Then,$$\frac{d(A_0-x)}{dt}=-k(A_0-x)(B_0-x)$$and$$\frac{d(B_0-x)}{dt}=-k(A_0-x)(B_0-x)$$Therefore, from both equations  $$\frac{dx}{dt}=k(A_0-x)(B_0-x)$$ subject to the initial condition x = 0 at t = 0.  This differential equation can readily be integrated using separation of variables and partial fractions.

Answer (score -1):

Given dX/dt = k[A][B] and A<sub>0</sub> and B<sub>0</sub> where you failed to define what X is, along with no value for k? It can not be done. see https://chem.libretexts.org/Core/Physical_and_Theoretical_Chemistry/Kinetics/Reaction_Rates/Second-Order_Reactions (and probably hundreds of other sites) for the integration over time. In short, a parameter x is inserted so that [A]= [A]<sub>0</sub>-x & [B]= [B]<sub>0</sub>-x, etc. and we integrate dx/dt which requires two cases: [A]<sub>0</sub> = [B]<sub>0</sub> and [A]<sub>0</sub> ≠ [B]<sub>0</sub> but I won't repeat the rest here. If they're equal [A] = [A]<sub>0</sub> ÷ ([A]<sub>0</sub>*k*t + 1) and if they're not equal then generally we consider the *ratio* of [A]:[B] but determining either [A] or [B] is simple ; i.e. don't replace [A]<sub>0</sub> - x, etc. with [A], etc. at equation 1.22 in the above link and then solve for x. Once you have x, you know [A]<sub>0</sub> - x, etc.

Comment: Situation 2a on that site was exactly what I was looking for -- thank you!